# How to pass a List of objects or a DOMSource as a parameter from java to xslt using Saxon 11.4 and Saxon9api?

Tags: java, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I want to pass a list of objects from java to xslt using saxon9api or pass the DOMSource if possible.

What i'm looking for is to generate an xslt by the xslt itself, i want to pass the list of nodes which they already have their childs...etc and i already have the java classes needed, i'm stuck to pass the list and loop it in xslt

I have tried implementing ExtensionFunction but it's not working for me, didn't found any useful tutorial nor a documentation

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve and how it fails. If you show the details of one particular attempt and how it failed exactly it might become clearer. In general, I don't see why you would want to use a DOMSource with Saxon and s9api to process or create XSLT; XSLT is XML so you can load it with the `doc` XPath function and you can output it like any other XML, with `xsl:output method="xml"`, perhaps needing to set up a namespace alias to have no collision between the `xsl` prefix used for your XSLT code and then prefix used for your (XSLT) result elements.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As for not finding documentation, see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/extensibility/extension-functions-J/ and https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/extensibility/extension-functions-J/ext-simple-J.html and https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/extensibility/extension-functions-J/ext-full-J.html for the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The comments address some of your subsidiary questions and describe ways you could improve your post. As to your headline question:

> How to pass a List of objects or a DOMSource as a parameter from java
> to xslt using Saxon 11.4 and Saxon9api?

The `XsltTransformer` class has a method `setParameter`, while `Xslt30Transformer` has `setParameters`; what they have in common is that you pass the values of the parameters as instances of `XdmValue`.

If you want to pass a list of strings as a parameter, convert each string to an `XdmAtomicValue` by calling `new XdmAtomicValue(str)`, then call `new XdmValue(Iterable<? extends XdmItem>)` or new `XdmValue(Iterator<? extends XdmItem>)` to convert the list of `XdmAtomicValue` objects into an `XdmValue` representing the sequence.

If you want to pass a DOM tree as a parameter (and I wouldn't normally recommend it, because using Saxon's native tree model is much faster), calling `DocumentBuilder.wrap(doc)` on the DOM `Document` node gives you an `XdmNode`, which is a subtype of `XdmValue`.